# A Witness Marsh puzzle having more than one correct answer [SPOILERS]

Tags: the-witness

I was quite confused because I believe to have an alternate solution to a Witness Marsh puzzle and this lead to me finally submitting and doing my first "cheating" and looking up a puzzle solution for Witness online. Which was too bad too because I was doing a good job of not cheating.

Here is the correct solution to the puzzle:

[image]

Here is the solution I had come up with, believe to be correct and started to make me question I understood the rules of the Marsh puzzles:

[image]

As I am playing Witness I often think about the developer of Witness and how he keeps one unique solution straight for many of these puzzles, a challenging problem for the developer for sure. So I understand if my alternate solution was just a "mistake" or an idiosyncrasy of the game where you have to believe you know the rules of the puzzles, and say to yourself, *my solution is correct, there is just another solution, I must let go of my correct solution, and move on to find another correct solution*.

** Caveat- And I also understand the some puzzles do have more than one solution, or at least I have seen one so far, in the Marsh to control the left and right direction of a platform but in that case you have a hit, the platform the puzzle is on that there is more than one solution to control flow.

Or, am I just wrong and my alternate solution is not a correct solution? My solution states that I can create 3x1 L shapes in any orientation, both my L shapes "point down". One 3x1 L is the "big spoon" of another 3x1 L and that other 3x1 L "spoons" the 3x2 grid:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your alternate solution is not correct.  You can rotate, not mirror, the reverse-L-shaped blocks.

Comment: Years later, I'm finally getting to this game, and this was the first thing I needed to look up. After searching for 30 minutes your answer finally did it, so thank you!

Comment: Pieces displayed at an angle can be rotated. Pieces displayed straight up and down must be traced as they are.